# Hourly version backup of Excel possibly using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, backup

I want to create hourly restore points of various documents (usually Excel 2010).  Is powershell suitable for doing this or is there anything built into Excel or off the shelf software that could do a better job?

Comment: This depends on your requirements and platform used (Windows file server, Sharepoint etc).

Answer (score 0):

Excel already does 10 minute autorecovery backups by default out of the box:

[image]

Comment: But doesn’t this just give the ability to revert to the last saved version?  What if I wanted to go back 3 versions?  I’m looking for hourly restore points.

Comment: take the AutoRecover file location path in the image above and write some powershell to copy all the files from that location to another location would seem like a simple solution for what you're after?

Comment: The was the essence of my first question. This answer, I'm afraid, does not answer anything.  My question was....Is powershell suitable for doing this or is there anything built into Excel or off the shelf software that could do a better job?

Comment: Ah apoligies, the my answer would be: PowerShell would be perfectly suitable for this and no, I do not believe Excel has anything built in to do this. The only thing excel does natively is the autosave function outlined above.